# "git log" output from Haskell's gitlib library?

Tags: git, haskell

I'm trying to get a value of type`[CommitObjOid]` in the form of `git log` (a list of commits to all files in the repository, sorted by date).

Although I'm familiar with how to interface with git as a end user, I'm not sure if the `git log` data is stored in some form of data structure?

How could this be accomplished with the `gitlib` haskell library? Would I need to aggregate a log based on each file in git repository?

Comment: I've never used it but it seems like you could accomplish this easily by iterating `lookupCommitParents`.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?